# Include pdftk in a distributable Python module

Tags: python, ghostscript, pdftk

How can I include pdftk and gsprint with a distributable Python program?

I've written [a short Python module](https://github.com/mmparker/printpack/blob/master/printpack.py) that takes several source PDFs, rearranges pages, and then prints them into correctly-ordered, helpfully-stapled packets (I'd be grateful for any feedback on the module [over on GitHub](https://github.com/mmparker/printpack/blob/master/printpack.py), too). This makes it a lot easier to print large numbers of these packets at once. I use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and [gsprint](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm) (via `subprocess.call`) to wrangle and print the PDFs.

Now, I'd like to be able to distribute this to my colleagues at other study sites around the country. I'm making three assumptions about them:

1. They are much less technically inclined than I am, so getting pdftk and gsprint installed and onto their system paths will probably be tough (assuming their local IT even permits such a thing);
2. They are almost all using Windows.
3. Users won't have Python installed (in reality some will, but who knows)

My *ideal* would be a single executable file that somehow has a Python interpreter, my module, pdftk, Ghostscript, and gsprint rolled up inside. Is that feasible, and if so, how? I've seen some tutorials on working with C and Java libraries, but it seems like I just don't have the vocabulary and conceptual knowledge to sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

To create a single standalone executable you can use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) *...totally self-contained, which runs without any external dependency.*

Comment: I'm not sure that will let me package non-Python libraries, though - all the examples cited are either Python modules or C libraries used through `ctypes`. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Thanks. Here's a [Google Group question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/PyInstaller/yDwJ0LxWztk/giCEW8mfgLUJ) that addresses my specific case in more detail; I'll give that a try, but it looks this should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to freeze your Python project, using a freezer for the purpose:

- http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.py2exe.org/

The task is usually as simple as executing a simple command, like `cxfreeze main.py --target-dir dist` or creating a `setup.py` file, where specific methods of the freezer are invoked. In most of the cases it would automatically figure the dependencies, but check the documentation.